# Plot many time series variables in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to plot multiple time series in R and cannot find a quicker way than making a plot with the first column of data and manually adding the next 30 columns to it:

```
plot(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,2],type="l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "", ylim=c(0,max+10))
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,3])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,4])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,5])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,6])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,7])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,8])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,9])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,10])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,11])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,12])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,13])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,14])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,15])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,16])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,17])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,18])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,19])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,20])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,21])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,22])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,23])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,24])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,25])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,26])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,27])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,28])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,29])
lines(x = SouthFOX[,1], y = SouthFOX[,30])
```

My data is a data.frame of 30 columns, with the first column as the Year, and the next 29 as measurements for each year for a given specimen:

```
> head(SouthFOX)
  Year  X050229  X050247
1 2005       NA       NA
2 2004 21.34867 16.46167
3 2003 23.89700 19.67367
4 2002 19.17867 16.91817
5 2001 31.69717 21.58650
6 2000 29.51600 20.72450
```

My desired graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnptr.jpg)

Ideally I would like to use ggplot2, but that does not seem to be working. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base-r you can use `matplot`:

```
mat <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol = 10)
df <- data.frame(year = 1:100, mat)

matplot(df$year, df[ ,-1], type = 'l')
```

[image]

For ggplot you need to restructure your data to the long format (e.g. using `reshape2::melt()`:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars = 'year')
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - the ggplot2 plot works. However I need all my lined to be black - how can I do that. If I remove the `color = variable` argument, the plot does not work.

Comment: use `group = variable` instead of `color = variable`. And make yourself comfortable with ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

Try [autoplot.zoo](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/autoplot.zoo) from the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html).  (To see each series in a separate panel omit `facets=NULL` .)

```
DF <- data.frame(year = 1:25, a = 1:25, b = 25:1) # test data

library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = identity)
autoplot(z, facets = NULL)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This works similarly with EDi's answer, but again I need to change all the lines to black and remove the legend. I can't seem to find how to do that with `autoplot`.

Comment: Try this: `autoplot(z, facet = NULL) + aes(colour = NULL)` and see the examples on `?autoplot.zoo` where there is an example which is nearly identical to this.